# javascript html5 file api get file type

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'm having some trouble tracking down why a file type is recoginsed on my machine by the JS file api, but not by my colleagues machine.

We're both running Chrome 28 and have a standard CSV which looks like:

```
xxx@bbb.com
yyy@ccc.ru
aaa@dddcom
```

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://example.com/content/email/">
    <label for="binFileToUpload">CSV to import</label>
    <input type="file" name="binFileToUpload" id="binFileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
</form>
```

and my JS looks like:

```
function fileSelected() {
    var file = document.getElementById('binFileToUpload').files[0];
    if (file) {
         var fileSize = 0;
         if (file.size < 1024 * 1024 * 4){
              if(file.type != 'application/vnd.ms-excel' && file.type != 'text/comma-separated-values' && file.type != 'text/csv' && file.type != 'application/csv' && file.type != 'text/anytext'){
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.SMESSAGE = "File type not supported.  Please only upload XLS or CSV files.";

                    errFunction(obj);
                    document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
                    document.getElementById('buttonupload').disabled = true;
              } else {
                    // do some stuff
              }
         }
    }
}
```

When i insert a `console.log(file)` just after i grab the file by id, my browser spits back:

```
name: "emails to send to.csv"
size: 137011
type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

amongst other things, whereas my colleague gets back

```
name: "emails to send to.csv"
size: 137011
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Why does the same file on my PC bring back a type but not on my colleagues pc?

Comment: If you are seeing different behaviors, then there must be some notable differences between the two machines.  Are you sure the file is the same in both instances?  How are you making sure?  Are you both using the same OS?

Comment: we're both running Windows 7.  He has MS Office 2000 and I MS Office 2010.  He emailed the file to me from his machine, and i saved it to a folder on my machine.

Comment: My guess is that the files are not in fact the same.  I would take a closer look at the two copies.

Comment: the mime types are pulled from the OS. your coworker has different file associations on his machine than you do... That said, who cares what the mime type is, the data is all the same.

Comment: @dandavis Can you cite your source on this?  I don't think you are correct.  I believe most if not all user agents simply match the file extension with a hard-coded table of MIME types.

Comment: @RayNicholus: \logic: if they are "both running Chrome 28", how could said hard-coded table differ between machines?

Comment: @dandavis I didn't say the tables differed.  I am suggesting that the files are, in fact, different in some way.  The Chromium source code seems to back up my assertion that MIME type are not in fact pulled from the OS and are pulled from code, unless I'm reading it wrong.  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/file_manager/js/file_type.js

Comment: @RayNicholus: i don't know how/where/if that table is used, or if it's just a default given no OS definition... i still don't see how it can differ if the user agent uses it's own table and the two machines in question use the same user agent. it shouldn't matter on the file contents at all, even if they are somehow different but the exact same size. if the browser uses the file extension, the actual contents of the file should be insignificant. can you explain the breakdown of my logic?

Comment: @dandavis I guess I'm saying the following: 1.) The OS is not involved as far as determination of MIME types as far as I can tell, and I have yet to find any evidence to the contrary.  2.) The OP is likely leaving something out of his/her post.  Perhaps the file extensions are not the same.  Perhaps the browsers are not the same.  It defies logic that two browsers on two different machines with the exact same file, OS, and browser would report different results, so something is missing here.  I would classify this as an impossible problem to diagnose as some important info is clearly missing.

Comment: @RayNicholus: i won't argue with that. maybe i'm out of date here. i know IE7 and early firefox actually sniffed the file contents to verify the contentType, and that upon installing some applications,  previous "unknown" mime types can come up with with the little icon and description....

Comment: @dandavis ... and I agree the contents of the file are likely not significant here.  The File API spec doesn't describe how MIME types should be determined by the UA at all, so it's anyone's guess how this actually works, but I'm not seeing anything in the source that suggests the OS is involved.  If you or anyone else has a link to another relevant section of the source, I would love to see it as I've wondered about this myself a bit.  Also, if anyone has found where the spec defines how a UA should determine the MIME type for a `Blob`, I'd also like to see that.  I'm hoping I just missed it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx  http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#method-getFileIcon   and a tiny hint about plugins here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file .  as best i can tell, i at least used to be right, maybe i still am or at least partially am...